# GEO and HEO images of Earth

Tags: orbit, earth

I would like to see some GEO and HEO images of Earth. But I can't find a good source. There are a lot of LEO images of Earth but I can'f find any raw images from higher (preferably 30,000km+) altitudes. There should be at least 400 satellites at that height, according to Wikipedia.

Is there any website with those kind of images?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at noaa.gov (https://www.nnvl.noaa.gov/view/globaldata.html in particular)

and similar sites for weather for other countries. In other words, the satellites in geostationary orbits (GEO) that take images are mostly weather satellite. I do not have a breakdown by type, but I would guess that a vast majority of the satellites in GEO are communication satellites, and they have no reason to take images.

I suspect that satellites in high earth orbit are there for astronomical purposes (to "get away" from the Earth, such as Chandra) or communication (such as the Russian Molniya satellites), so they are not imaging the Earth.

Comment: Do you know of a good site that has the whole hemisphere GEOS, Meteosat and Himawari images. The global data viewer has lots of sources, and its not clear which source comes from which satellite.